# How do you rip a VCD on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, dvd

**What's the most popular way of ripping a VCD to an .m4v file?** I also need to pick a particular audio track (Chinese vs. English).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Handbrake is a nice program that you can use to convert videos and DVDs. Since VCDs are nothing more than mpeg files (with .dat) extension, you can easily use Handbrake to transcode them to m4v.

Handbrake also allows you to select which tracks you want to keep, although if each track is its own file, you may need to use MP4Box to merge them together.

Handbrake is available at http://handbrake.fr, and MP4Box can be downloaded from http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/.

Comment: Works great. For those who need a bit more direction on using Handbrake with a VCD: in Handbrake, go to File > Open Source, navigate to the MPEGAV folder of your VCD and select the biggest .dat file there. To select an audio channel (stereo, left, right), go to the Audio tab and change the value under the Mixdown column.

Comment: those .DAT are actually MPG file plus some extra data... some people say if you rename them as .MPG you will get side effects, and VCDGear or ISOBuster can do the job more correctly... in terms of whether HandBrake can handle it without VCDGear or ISOBuster, that I don't know yet